# Is console app parameter in react.js code outside serverless.yaml?

Tags: serverless-framework

I want to print an env variable to console.

I added following veriables in parameters of Serverless app console

```
in dev: "TESTNAME" : "dev test name"
in prod: "TESTNAME" : "prod test name"
```

And in js file in my React.js project, I tried

```
console.log(process.env.TESTNAME);
```

But it returns nothing.

How come it doesn't work?